# implicit declaration of function ‘bpf’

Tags: bpf, ebpf

I have been studying BPF recently, but it is not proceeding because of a very basic problem.

I included linux/bpf.h as described in man bpf(2), but GCC can not find bpf function. This code is just for the test to make sure that GCC can find bpf function.

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>

int main()
{
    bpf(0,(void *)0,0);
    return 0;
}
```

GCC output is this.

```
$ gcc -o test bpf.c
bpf.c: In function ‘main’:
bpf.c:5:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘bpf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  bpf(0,(void *)0,0);
  ^~~
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc4tjrUh.o: in function `main':
bpf.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `bpf'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using Archlinux and linux kernel version is 4.20.11-arch1-1-ARCH.
Please help me how to include bpf function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The manual page documents the system call `bpf`. While this is not intuitive, there is actually no function defined in the header `<linux/bpf.h>` that is simply called `bpf()`. Instead, you can do an indirect syscall with `syscall(__NR_bpf, ...)` (see also `man syscall`).

Projects relying on this syscall often define a wrapper that looks like this:

```c
int bpf(enum bpf_cmd cmd, union bpf_attr *attr, unsigned int size)
{
    return syscall(__NR_bpf, cmd, attr, size);
}
```

Here is [an example from libbpf](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20/source/tools/lib/bpf/bpf.c#L62).

Comment: Finally it worked! Thank you very much. By the way, some example use something like BPF_MOV64_IMM macros but it doesn't defined in linux/bpf.h. how can I use that?

Comment: I don't believe these macros are exposed to user space. They are defined in a [kernel header](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20/source/include/linux/filter.h#L148) so kernel code can access them. Samples in kernel sources [link to it](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20/source/samples/bpf/Makefile#L269) (`LINUXINCLUDE`). Libbpf and co do use the macros as well, but they exported it [in a header under `tools/`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20/source/tools/include/linux/filter.h#L98), which is not copied and made available at the system level.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your detailed answer.